# Pass data between three viewController, all in navigationController, popToRootView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The issue I'm having is this.

I have a navigation controller with 3 viewController. In the 1st controller, I have the user select an image. This image is passed to 2nd and 3rd controller via prepareForSegue.

At the 3rd controller, I have a button that takes the user back to the 1st view controller. I explored 2 ways in doing this:
1) use performSegue, but I don't like this because it just push the 1st controller to my navigation stack. So I have this weird "Back" button at the 1st Viewcontroller now, which is not what I want. I want the app to take user directly to 1st viewcontroller without the back button.

2) I tried Poptorootviewcontroller. This solves the issue of the "back" button. But, when I pop back to the 1st viewcontroller, the user's selected image is still on screen. I want to clear this image when the user goes from the 3rd viewcontroller back to the 1st viewcontroller.

So with approach 2), how do I make sure all memory is refreshed and the image becomes nil in the 1st viewcontroller? Since I'm not using performSegue, 3rd viewcontroller does not have access to the 1st Viewcontroller.

Comment: i need the code of 1st view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For refresh, you'd have to clear it in viewWillAppear but I find this rather dangerous. Best you can do there is to create a new copy of the view controller everytime and Swift will take care of the rest. I don't know if you are using the storyboard but I would recommend using the class UIStoryboard and the function instiantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("something") as! YourCustomVC
As long as you stay in the navigation stack, you'll not lose any of the current configurations of previous View Controllers.

As for passing data back to the first controller. You can either just throw it in the global scope which is the easiest way but might be difficult to know when it was updated or if the data is fresh. But you can always just:

```
 var something: String = ""
 class someView: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           something = "foo"
      }
 }
```

Something will be availabe everywhere then.

You could make a protocol and pass the delegate along the 3 view controllers. So when you are starting it you could do:

```
func someAction() {
    let v = SomeViewController()
    v.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
}
```

And then with each following view:

```
func someOtherAction() {
    let v = SomeOtherViewController()
    v.delegate = self.delegate
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
}
```

Although personally I find it hard to keep track of this.

Lastly you could use the NSNotificationCenter to pass an object along with all the data and catch it in a function on your first controller.
To do this you first register your VC for the action in viewDidLoad() or something:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "someAction:", name: "someNotification", object: nil)
```

Then when you are done in the 3rd view make some object or a collection of string and send it back as follows:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("someNotification", object: CustomObject())
```

And then lastly you'll catch it in the function "someAction"

```
func someAction(note: NSNotification) { 
    if let object = note.object as? CustomObject {  
          //Do something with it
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use an [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) which provides the functionality to unwind from the 3rd to the 1st (root) view controller.

The unwind segue is tied to an action in the root view controller.  Within this action, you simply nil the image:

```
@IBAction func unwindToRootViewController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.

    // Nil the selected image
    myImageView.image = nil
}
```

As you can see in the action, segues also let you pass data back from the source view controller. This is a much simpler approach than needing to resort to using delegates, notifications, or global variables.

It also helps keep things encapsulated, as the third view controller should never need to know specifics about a parent view controller, or try to nil any image that belongs to another view controller.

In general, you pass details to a controller, which then acts on it itself, instead of trying to manipulate another controller's internals.

Comment: Thanks all! Your answers helped me understand how segues work. Also, I found another way to solve my issue. 

Instead of clearing my image in my 1st VC from my 3rd VC, I just cleared it in my 2nd VC with the delegate/protocol method. Thanks again!

Comment: @HeavyBreathing There are many design patterns. Just remember that in one of the methods, the 1st VC clears its own image. You have more choices now in the design of your apps and their VCs!